# How can I save to a different collection using Morphia?

Tags: mongodb, save, morphia

Lets assume I have a class `Foo` that is annotated for use in Morphia

```
@Entity("Foo")
public class Foo{
    ...
}
```

Most of the time when I read/write `Foo` from the database I want to use the `Foo` collection

```
datastore.save(foos);
```

but sometimes I want to read/write to the `Bar` collection. How can I save `Foo` to collection `Bar` in Morphia?

Answer (score 3):

You can cast the `Datastore` to `AdvancedDatastore` and call [`save(String kind, T entity)`](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/1.0/javadoc/org/mongodb/morphia/AdvancedDatastore.html#save(java.lang.String,%20T)).

Comment: I gave that a shot but I get `Exception in thread "main" org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class Foo`.  Does kind need to be an already existing entity?

Comment: "kind" is just a collection name.  Not sure why you'd be getting that one.  I'll look at the tests and make sure we're covering this use case.

Comment: You can find a repro the bug [here](https://goo.gl/BxYE9M). Just do a vanilla run of the `CwacDemoApp` and you should see the exception on line 28.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only option would be subclassing:

```
@Entity("Bar")
public class Bar extends Foo {
```

You'd need to instantiate the right class, but should be able to avoid code duplication.

If you have a common base class (`public class Foo extends Base`) you could use common queries on persist, get,... based on generics:

```
public <E extends Base> void persist(E entity) {
      mongoDataStore.save(entity);
}
public <E extends Base> E get(Class<E> clazz, ObjectId id) {
    return mongoDataStore.find(clazz).field("id").equal(id).get();
}
```

Then you could simply do something like this:

```
Bar bar = new Bar();
persistenceService.persist(bar);
Foo foo = new Foo();
persistenceService.persist(foo);
Bar barFetched = persistenceService.get(Bar.class, ...);
```

Comment: But then I need to cast down to `bar`, which is less than ideal

Comment: Ok, I've added more code. In which situation would you require casting?